# Calculate total working days left of the month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

Below is my code to calculate the total amount of working days in the current month.

```
DECLARE @my int
DECLARE @myDeduct int
DECLARE @day INT
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME

SET @mydate = getDate()

SET @myDeduct = 0
SET DateFirst 1 -- Set it monday=1 (value)

--Saturday and Sunday on the first and last day of a month will Deduct 1
IF (DATEPART(weekday,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate))) > 5)
SET @myDeduct = @myDeduct + 1

IF (DATEPART(weekday,(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))),
                                                 DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate)))) > 5)
SET @myDeduct = @myDeduct + 1

SET @my = day(DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))),DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate)))

select (((@my/7) * 5 + (@my%7)) - @myDeduct) as Working_Day_per_month
```

How can I now calculate how many of those working days are left for the current month?
Not worried about public holidays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

This Query will give you working days in the current month..Assuming non working days are Saturdays and Sundays. If you have a table which contains list of working days/holidays then you can join that table also with the query to get the correct result..

```
SELECT number+1 as 'day'
FROM   master..spt_values
WHERE  type='p'
AND    number <datepart(dd, DateAdd(day,-1,DateAdd(Month,1,DateAdd(Month,
                                          DateDiff(Month, 0, GETDATE()),0))))
AND    datename(WEEKDAY,DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, GetDate()),
                                         number) ) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')
```

Comment: Thanks, see my answer below on how I used it with a CTE

Answer (score 1):

I used **Joe G Joseph** answer and altered it like this!

```
Declare @DaysLeft as INT

;With MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT number + 1 as 'CurrentDay'
    FROM   master..spt_values
    WHERE  type='p'
    AND    number < datepart(dd, DateAdd(day,-1,DateAdd(Month,1,DateAdd(Month,
                                          DateDiff(Month, 0, GETDATE()),0))))
    AND    datename(WEEKDAY,DateAdd(Month, DateDiff(Month, 0, GETDATE()),
                                         number) ) not in ('Saturday','Sunday')
)

Select @DaysLeft = (Select COUNT(*) As MyTotal from MyCTE
WHERE CurrentDay >= DATEPART(DD, GETDATE()))

Select @DaysLeft
```